# Copy S3 File to Docker Image via Dockerfile

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that installs awscli and then tries to run aws s3 cp to get a file and put it on the docker image.

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM my-kie-server:latest

USER root
RUN echo "ip_resolve=4" >> /etc/yum.conf

ENV http_proxy host.docker.internal:9000
ENV https_proxy host.docker.internal:9000
ENV HTTP_PROXY host.docker.internal:9000
ENV HTTPS_PROXY host.docker.internal:9000

RUN yum install -y maven
RUN yum install -y awscli

USER jboss

ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

RUN aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myPath/myFile.jar x.jar
```

But when I build the image I get this error:

> fatal error: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:618)
>   The command '/bin/sh -c aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myPath/myFile.jar x.jar' returned a non-zero code: 1

I have tried using --no-verify-ssl on the aws s3 cp command but get the same error.

I've found very little online that mentions this UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL error. Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: why are the Proxy Envs ? I think they  make the problem

Comment: I work behind a company proxy so had to add those to get yum to download packages. But I was wondering if the proxy was intefering with SSL somehow.

Comment: Yes I think so , that the most common problem

Comment: Building inside an internal network behind a proxy connecting to an AWS s3 bucket to fetch data during a build? What kind of proxy are we talking about (i.e. `squid`, `nexus`, unknown)?

Comment: I managed to confirm that the issue is our proxy.